# Intermittent logging of completion logs

Tags: azure-functions

I've got a function app deployed with Application Insights instrumentation. That function app has a BlobTrigger function that performs a LogInformation call as its final step of the function to write out metrics of data being processed. I'm noticing that that final log message is not consistently being captured in Application Insights based on a transaction search. In addition, the "out of the box" completion message (Executed 'MyFunction' (Succeeded, Id=some-guid, Duration=99ms) is also missing when my custom message is missing and is there when my custom message is there.

As far as I can tell, the function completed successfully. There are no exceptions in the logs and the last action it takes before writing the log message is to output a blob and that was successful. What can I look at to see why the completion messages aren't logging? Could the function instance be terminating before the logs are written? (That seems likely, except that both my custom log and the framework log are both missing).

Comment: Is in your host.json, `samplingSettings` is enabled? `{
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  }
}`. If yes, disable it...

Comment: Yes, it is. I would have thought logs wouldn't be limited by sampling. I think rather than turning this off, I'd like to include Exception and Trace in the categories to exclude. That basically leaves dependency traces out, which is fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer was the telemetry sampling. I don't want to completely remove it since I don't want to be overrun with dependency logs, but i did add a few more categories to ensure traces are always logged.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-sampling